# C# passing generic functions as parameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to audit method calls from within the application so that I can profile and analyze the parameters.  I got this to work,

```
Run( ()=> SomeFunction(paramA, paramB), paramA, paramB) );

public static void Run(Expression<Action> action, params object[] param)
{
   var func = action.Compile();
   func();
}

public static T Run<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action, params object[] param)
{
   var func = action.Compile();
   return func();
}
```

However I was hoping to lose the lambda and make the method even easier to use.  For example,

```
Run(SomeFunc, paramA, paramB);
```

I got to here, but I'm stumped, in case someone can help me out:

```
private T Run<T>(Func<T> subReturn) {}
```

Comment: You are not using `param` that you pass into your `Run<T>` methods. Is that intentional?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "profile and analyze the parameters"?

Comment: How many different functions do you have, and how much variation is there in terms of number/types of parameters?  But more curiously, why do you consider `Run(SomeFunc, paramA, paramB)` easier to use than `Run(() => SomeFunc(paramA, paramB))` ? As others have pointed out, you don't need to pass the parameters in twice, they're already there as part of the `Expression< >`, though you will need to parse it to extract them.

Comment: You can find some information on C# interception here: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/interception-in-net-part-4-an-interception-framework

Comment: Pulling out the parameters by evaluating the Expression worked well to avoid the redundant parameters on "Run" Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you want exactly, but if I understand it correctly, than this might help:

```
private T Run<T, TLeft, TRight>(Func<TLeft, TRight, T> action, TLeft leftParam, TRight rightParam)
{
    return action(leftParam, rightParam);
}
```

Comment: This is correct -- add sixteen more overloads for `Func<T>` through `Func<T1,...T16, TResult>` and another seventeen or so for `Action` through `Action<T1,...T16>`, and you can treat yourself to a nice cold beer. Which you'll need.

Comment: Yeah. Hahaha :D

Comment: Using `Func<TLeft, TRight>` means you lose the information captured by `Expression<>`, including the name of the function etc.

Comment: To be honest, I don't even know what he wants to achive.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I thought about explaining more, but I didn't want the question to be too wordy.  I'm trying to capture and save how long certain methods take to run and what parameters were used.  I'm trying to come up with a method that's as simple as possible, that will work for every scenario, ex: SomeFunc(), SomeFunc(123, "abc"), var x = SomeFunc(1,3,4, ["a","b", "c"]) etc.  I was wondering if there was a way to do that without an overload for every scenario, but if that's the only option then it works for me!  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Sean Your question would be improved if you added that paragraph to it. There's no such thing as "too wordy" if the words explain something important about the problem.

Comment: @Sean Hmm. Let me think of something.

Comment: @DylanNicholson A bare method name ("method group") will not convert implicitly to an `Expression<>` the way it will do to a plain delegate type. So if you want to be able to do `var r = Run(SomeMethod);` where `SomeMethod` is the name of a C# method, it cannot work with `Expression<>`. You will be forced to `var r = Run(() => SomeMethod());` in that case.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that @JeppeStigNielsen, just making ensure the OP understands that they'll no longer have access to the method name etc. using the suggested answer.

Comment: @Sean You could use the classes MethodInfo, Delegate to make it easier to use, but you just can't make it as dynamic as you want it, because of the language limitations (there is no common "ancestor" of the different delegate types).